# Accessing a item inside the object

Tags: objective-c, for-in-loop

I'm using matrix chat in my application, i have stored all the details of the room inside the array and I'm looping in for in condition, so inside that I have to access the roomDislayname inside the object.

```
for (MXKRecentCellData * cellData in dataArray) {
}
```

[image]

In the above picture i have to access the roomDisplayname which is of dictonary type. Can anyone help me with this?????

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows the `roomDisplayname` is a string (`_NSCFString`) not a dictionary.

However the value of that string looks like a JSON representation of a dictionary value. So you need to lookup how to convert JSON structured text into object values, which will give you your dictionary.

If you hit a problem handling the JSON ask a new question showing what you have developed, explaining your issue, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help you along. HTH

Comment: thanks for you comment, but my question is how to access the that roomDisplayname (_NSCFString) which is in JSON structured

Comment: OK, I am not sure what you need. To access the (string valued) property use `cellData.roomDisplayname`, is that what you need?

Comment: If we access like that its taking the roomDisplayname outside i.e Adel Al-Ghamdi

Comment: OK, I missed what you appear to have done here – you have extended a class (`MXKRecentCellData`) with your own class (`RecentCellData`) and hidden a property (`roomDisplayname`) of the former by defining a new version in your extending class. You need to edit your question, show the relevant code relating to `RecentCellData` and state *where* you are trying to access the hidden field (e.g. from a method of `RecentCellData`, from code outside both classes, etc.). State whether you intended to hide a field you need to access or whether you didn't intend to hide it but do something else. [cont]

Comment: [cont] Once you've edited your question someone will probably help you out. HTH